# Filtering rows before a certain criteria by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to figure out how I can filter rows in pandas based on a certain criteria that changes for each group. See dummy data here and the desired result.

Dummy data

```
data = {'ID':['1111', '1111', '1111', '1111','1112','1112','1112','1112','1112'],
        'Category':[1,2,2,2,1,3,2,2,1]}
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
ID      Category
1111    1
1111    2
1111    2
1111    2
1112    1
1112    3
1112    2
1112    2
1112    1
```

Now I am trying to filter the dataframe such that *for each* `ID` it picks all the rows *before* the first occurrence of `Category 2`. This is how the desired result would look like

```
ID      Category
1111    1
1112    1
1112    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[(df['Category'] != 2).groupby(df['ID']).cumprod()]
```

Output:

```
     ID  Category
0  1111         1
4  1112         1
5  1112         3
```

**Details:**
Create a boolean series where True when Category is not equal to 2, then use cumprod such that the first False Category = 2, it remains False for each group.

Comment: It's always confused me why pandas doesn't have something such as a `.partitionby` method... wonder if I ever get around to it I might propose that... *shrugs*...

Comment: @JonClements What do you see the difference between groupby and partitionby?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.loc[df.Category.eq(2).groupby(df.ID).cumsum().eq(0)]
#      ID  Category
# 0  1111         1
# 4  1112         1
# 5  1112         3
```